# got error while setting default image in ImageField Django

Tags: django, django-models

my model have an imagefield which stores the image for post . I want to add default image to that in case if not is not uploaded.But I am getting error **The 'title_image' attribute has no file associated with it**. If I upload image then its working fine.

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='Images/PostTitleImages/',
         max_length=None,
         default = 'Images/Image_not_found.jpg',
         blank = True,
         null = True)
```

**home.html**

```
<img src="{{post.title_image.url}}"  height="350px"/>
```

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
]

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('MainSite.urls'), name = "Main"),
    path('account/',include('account.urls'), name = 'Accounts')
] 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

what I am doing wrong here I checked the file is in this directory **/media/Images/PostTitleImages/**

Answer (score 0):

In case of `media` you need to include the media tag in your template like so:

```
# template

<img src="{{ media_url }}{{ post.title_image.url }}>
```

and in your settings add the [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/)

```
# settings.py

'django.template.context_processors.media'
```

Comment: I added ```'django.template.context_processors.media'``` under Templates context_processors  and added ```{{media_url}}``` in template but nothing happened

Comment: try update your media settings into `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

Comment: I dont know why but I flush the database and now its working